# SCCM 2012 Windows PE issues

Tags: sccm-2012, windows-pe, netboot

Just got some lenovo X240, i7 with touch screen..
 I got two issues when trying to enter Windows PE. (PE enviroment is 8.1)

1: First of all I don't get anything in the 'image selection: .. its blank..
 The task sequence I use works perfectly on the X240, i5 machine, and most definetly have a capture image assigned.

I'm guessing its because the new i7 machine has SSD?, and not Harddisk. Thats at least the only major difference I can find.

but what confuses me is the fact
 that I'm able to see the volume.. C:\Windows8_OS .. and I would think that would be the one missing if it was a driver issue?

I've not added any drivers for the model to the boot image, simply because so far from 6 different models, one of them being another x240, I've not had to do so..
 when trying to deploy windows 8.1 in windows pe 8.1

how do I figure out if its a driver I need?

2: this is an absurd one

I only get to see half the Windows PE screen..
 Yes the resolution on the WIndows PE menu is so low on this monitor, that I simply can't see more than half selections.
 How on earth can I control the resolution of the boot image?

Answer (score 3):

I'd try to check the SMSTS.log file on a machine that can see the advertised task sequences, and compare that to one of your machines that's not seeing the advertisements and see if there are any clues for where the issue may lie. Even if you haven't selected and launched a task sequence, you should have a log in X:\Windows\temp\SMSTSLog\smsts.log

As far as the video issue, try adding a video driver to the boot image to see if that helps the display issue. I've also read from other sources that you can set the WinPE resolution via an unattend.xml:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766521(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope this helps, or someone with additional experience can chime in!

EDIT: Looks like Niall over at Windows-Noob has a post addressing a similar issue as far as the video issue:  http://www.windows-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/11148-how-can-i-display-video-correctly-in-winpe-during-uefi-network-boot-on-a-lenovo-thinkpad-10-using-system-center-2012-r2-configuration-manager/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to checking the SMSTS.log file that was already mentioned, a couple of things:

- It shouldn't matter if the laptop has an SSD, it's all about drivers. In your case, the hard drive controller (AKA *Storage*) Drivers.
- The other main driver is the nic driver. If your machine boots up to the image, but your Task Sequence selection window is blank or shows no task sequences, then check your task sequence advertisement settings and make sure that machine is in the proper collection, and also make sure there are no duplicate guids in sccm, that would cause the same issue.
- Definitely add drivers, and don't go off of the assumption that the drivers are "built in". I don't know about Lenovo, but Dell has "driver packs" that are designed to be imported directly to the wim, so that all their relevant models will have drivers when imaging.
- The second issue is also most likely driver related, if not, I would still start there in my troubleshooting.